# Regex for 10-15 digit phone number validation

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, phone-number

I'd like to write a custom jQuery validator method to validate a phone number and I need help with the regex for it.

It's for international phone number so it needs to accept only 10-15 digits. One more condition here is that I have a phone mask already in place:
`+___ ___ ___ ___ ___` (There's `+` and 15 counts of underscores here).

The regex should possibly ignore the +, and the underscores, and any number of digits that is between 10-15 should be accepted as a valid phone number.
[screenshot of the phone area field is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyA8q.png)

Possible accepted numbers:

```
+2345678901_____
+23456789012____
+234567890123___
+2345678901234__
+23456789012345_
+234567890123456
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following pattern would seem to work here:

```
^\+(?=.{15})\d{10,15}_{0,5}$
```

This uses a positive lookahead to assert that exactly 15 characters, excluding the leading `+`, occur in the input.  With that assertion in place, we can match for 10-15 digits, followed by 0-5 underscores.

### Demo